# Library not Found pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[here is he image of the output hope it will help you find my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfyIw.png)Hey there I am using latest version of Python I have been trying for days to convert a python file into .exe file using pyinstaller here is what I type "pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=icon.ico file_name.py"
whenever I run this it shows me that is couldn't find my library of pyttsx3 it shows like "warn" then "lib not found" plz help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please copy the error message from your image into the answer. This is important for the search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal and type `pip uninstall pyttsx3` and then run this `pip install pyttsx3==2.71` 
It should work for you

Comment: 5955 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\muzzamil\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll this is what it showed after what you told me to do

Comment: I have added the image maybe that will help you find my answer